# Find the best method to merging multiple widgets in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

can you guys tell me what is the best method to merging some widgets. so i can destroy them or append them on the window?

i have a method to do that, but i don`t know is this an efficient method or not since im using list and use for loop to destroy them. Let me know what is the best method to do that. Im sorry for my bad english, Thanks.

```py
class X(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lst_element = []
        self.butt_plus = tk.Button(self, text="+", command=self.add_element)
        self.butt_min = tk.Button(self,text="-", command=self.del_element)

        self.butt_plus.grid(row=1, column=0,padx = 5, pady=2)
        self.butt_min.grid(row=1, column=1,padx = 5, pady=2)

    def elements(self):
        self.subject = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.weight = tk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.dot = tk.Label(self, text="●")
        self.arrow = tk.Label(self, text="=>")

        self.lst_element.append([self.subject, self.weight, self.dot, self.arrow])

        self.dot.grid(row=len(self.lst_element)-1, column=2)
        self.subject.grid(row=len(self.lst_element)-1, column=3, padx = 5, pady=2)
        self.arrow.grid(row=len(self.lst_element)-1, column=4)
        self.weight.grid(row=len(self.lst_element)-1, column=5, padx = 5, pady=2)
        
        
    def add_element(self):
        self.elements()
        print(self.lst_element)
    
    def del_element(self):
        if len(self.lst_element) != 1:
            for e in self.lst_element[-1]:
                e.destroy()
            self.lst_element.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put those widgets in a frame, then you can simply destroy the frame when the <kbd>-</kbd> button is clicked:

```py
class X(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lst_element = []
        self.butt_plus = tk.Button(self, text="+", command=self.add_element)
        self.butt_min = tk.Button(self,text="-", command=self.del_element)

        self.butt_plus.grid(row=1, column=0,padx = 5, pady=2)
        self.butt_min.grid(row=1, column=1,padx = 5, pady=2)

    def elements(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid(row=len(self.lst_element), column=2)

        subject = tk.Entry(frame, width=15)
        weight = tk.Entry(frame, width=7)
        dot = tk.Label(frame, text="●")
        arrow = tk.Label(frame, text="=>")

        dot.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        subject.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=2)
        arrow.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        weight.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=2)

        # don't need to save those labels if they are not referenced later
        self.lst_element.append([frame, subject, weight])

    def add_element(self):
        self.elements()
        print(self.lst_element)

    def del_element(self):
        if self.lst_element:
            # get the last row and destroy the frame
            self.lst_element.pop()[0].destroy()
```